# linux kernel parameter 'rootwait' being ignored

Tags: linux, kernel, debian

according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt the parameter 'rootwait' should cause the kernel to wait indefinitely for the root device to show up.

This does not seem to work for me here - after a few seconds I get dropped to the shell instead.

I set up a fully encrypted dedicated server, and thus need to unlock it remotely. I configured cryptsetup to keep trying to read the device key from a file. When I want to unlock the server I just copy the keyfile to the server via SSH (dropbear) and the server continues to boot.

Problem here is that if I wait too long, the kernel will drop to a shell and will not automatically mount rootfs and continue booting anymore.

I'm using debian and the latest 3.2.0-4-rt-amd64 kernel from wheezy repository.

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rootwait` kernel parameter only affects the first stage of boot, while the *kernel* is waiting for its initial root device. From what you're describing, the kernel has already mounted some sort of root device (either a stub root or an initramfs) and started executing startup scripts, so the `rootwait` parameter no longer applies -- whatever timeout is firing is specified somewhere else. You'll need to look at the startup scripts that are handling this and modify them appropriately.

Comment: so you say _rootwait_ does not wait for the device specified by _root=_?

Comment: If the server is getting far enough to start an SSH server, it's gone beyond the point where `rootwait` is relevant. That parameter only applies when the kernel is waiting for a root device before **anything** else has started, even `init`.

Comment: Well, thank you for your help then. I guess I have to crawl through the startup scripts now... Have a nice day :-)

Comment: I have a comparable issue with an LSI HBA on a newly setup server with lots of disks connected through internal and external shelves. After loading the driver, it takes nearly two minutes for all disks to appear (at once). A few weeks ago, I added rootwait to grub and the box booted happily and cleanly after all disks appeared. After a reboot (kernel update), the old behavior has appeared: Drop into initramfs, because not all disks are there. cat /proc/cmdline shows rootwait. I don't know what changed, yet.